# How to extract Seq[String] from Option[Seq[Case Class]]

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a json and i parse the json to the below case classes. I use play json for parsing.
Below are my case classes

```
case class Result(id: String, account : Option[Seq[Account],data: Option[Seq[Data]])
case class Account(accountId: Option[String] = None)
case class Data(primaryId: Option[String] = None,
                            accountId: Option[String] = None)
```

From the Data case class I need all the primaryId as  Seq[String]  that matches the accountId of the Data case class with the accountId of Account case class.

The following is the snippet of code that i have tried. I  tried it doing in 2 ways

First way

```
primaryIds = data.map(cd =>
            for{
                c <- cd
              if c.relatedAccountId == account.accountId
            }yield c.primaryId.get)))
```

Second way

```
primaryIds = data.map(_.collect {
                    case s if s.relatedAccountId.equals(account.accountId) & s.primaryId.isDefined => s.primaryId.get
```

Here are my questions

Is it correct to use s.primaryId.get. What if s.primaryId is None. And None.get will throw an exception.
Is there a better way to handle this. Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
result.data.map{ cd =>
  cd.filter(c => account.exists(_.accountId == c.accountId))
    .flatMap(_.primaryId.toList)
}.getOrElse(Seq.empty[String])
```

`Option[T]` has a `toList` method that works nicely when you want to `flatMap` with a `Seq[Option[T]]`. 
Never use `Option.get`. The `getOrElse` method returns a default value (`Seq.empty[String]`) if the option is `None`.

Also, You should look into simplifying the types you are using in your case classes. Instead of using `Option[Seq[T]]`, use a regular `Seq[T]`. You can represent the missing value with an empty list `Seq.empty`. This small change will make a big difference because it simplifies your ability to work with your data.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always bad idea to use `.get` on `Option[_]`. Moreover in first way you compare options. It's not a good idea, because it may result in some strange result (`None` == `None` => `true`).

Instead of getting value of accountId you can use `flatMap` like this

```
primaryIds = data.map(cd =>
        cd.flatMap{
           case Data(maybePrimaryId, Some(accountId)) if currentAccount.accountId.contains(accountId) => maybePrimaryId
          case _ => None
        }
```

Comment: I have few questions here

Comment: 1.In Case Data(maybePrimaryId,Some(accountId)) why is maybePrimaryId not Some(maybePrimaryId) since it is also an Option[String] . 2. What happens when either of maybePrimaryId or Some(accountId) is None . AFAIK the control goes here case Data(maybePrimaryId, Some(accountId)) when values for both maybePrimaryId, Some(accountId) are present. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: 1) It could be Some(primaryId), but then you should use `map` instead of `flatMap` and you should return primaryId.
2) Not really, the control goes to `case Data(maybePrimaryId, Some(accountId))` when `accountId` from your model is present, but it's possible that `maybePrimaryId` is `None`